# C# Task wait and timeout

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to use the following technique to be able to have a worker task executing some operations, with a 10 sec timeout and without blocking the application.

```
internal void ReadAll()
{
    var data = new byte[1];

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ReadAllTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Read all information
            // [omit communication exchange via COM port]

            ct.Cancel();
        }, ct.Token);

        // First thread waiting 10s for the worker to finish
        ReadAllTask.Wait(10000, ct.Token);

        if (ReadAllTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(true);
        }
        else
        {
            ct.Cancel();
            ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(false);
        }
    });
}
```

This method is called by pressing a button. It seems to me that in debug configuration works properly, but not in release configuration where the "first thread" never reach the wait and no event is thrown.

Comment: Are there any exceptions? Exceptions thrown on thread-pool threads are now silently ignored by default, so make sure they are handled properly.

Comment: [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) use `Task.Run` instead or at minimum pass in a `TaskSchedueller.Default` in to prevent potential errors where reentrant code can end up running on the UI thread.

Comment: Are you sure `ReadAllComplete` isn't null in release form?  Are you sure there are no exceptions?  Have you tried adding some additional logging methods and try/catches?

Comment: @Luaan AFAIK No exceptions are raised. I'll try to look for thread-pool exceptions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Already tried to use task.Run instead... same result. I'll try the `TaskSchedueller.Default`

Comment: @Zag `Task.Run` was not intended as a solution just the best way to queue a task. Your operation seems IO bound, is there no async api available? If not at least change your method to return a task that can be awaited up to your UI which would allow you to get rid of the event.

Comment: Actually I can catch an exception: `Error: the operation was cancelled. mscorlib`

Comment: Why do you call `ct.Cancel();` inside the the inner StartNew?

Comment: Just remove `ct.Cancel()` and that will likely solve your problem, since canceling a `Task` causes a `TaskCanceledException` to be thrown, and since you are not handling the exception it will cause the thread to silently exit, as @Luaan mentioned.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain worker thread ended the communication, so I want to stop the timeout/waiting thread

Comment: Why? The when the task ends, it will cause the wait to complete. That's the whole point of waiting on a task :)

Comment: @Luaan I didn't know it. TY

Answer (score 2):

Your code could be a lot simpler than current version. Easiest way to make a non-blocking method for event is to mark it with `async` keyword and use the `await` keyword to start the [asynchronous read operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669.aspx) from [`SerialPort.BaseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream.aspx) property.

Also, `CancellationTokenSource` could be created with time, after that it get cancelled automatically, and the right way to cancel is to call [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx) method. `async/await` mechanism will invoke the event in UI context, so code could be something like this:

```
// async void is a recommended way to use asynchronous event handlers
private async void btnReadAll_Click(object sebder, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = new byte[2];

    // cancel source after 10 seconds
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
    // Read all information
    // [omit communication exchange via COM port]
    // async operation with BaseStream
    var result = await SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 2, cts.Token);

    /*
     * if you can't use the BaseStream methods, simply call this method here
     * cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    */

    // this code would run only if everything is ok

    // check result here in your own way
    var boolFlag = result != null;

    ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(boolFlag);
}
```

Comment: Cannot use basestream, but I need someone awaiting

Comment: Then you can use a `TaskCompletionSource` as awaitable thing

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a quick rewrite to remove the event and wrap what appears to be a synchronous IO API in an async one. If at all possible you should switch to a true async API and drop the `Task.Run`.

```
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public async void MyButtonhandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try {
            var result = await Task.Run(() => ReadAll(cts));
            if (result) {
                //success
            } else {
                //failure
            }
        } catch (TaskCanceledException ex) {

        }            
    }

    internal async Task<bool> ReadAll(CancellationTokenSource cts) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1];
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        var ReadAllTask = Task.Run(() => {
            // Read all information
            // [omit communication exchange via COM port]

        }, cts.Token);

        if (await Task.WhenAny(ReadAllTask, Task.Delay(timeout)) == ReadAllTask) {
            return true;
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading comments and answers to my question I learned a couple of useful things that solve my problem:

- CancellationTokenSource can have an implicit timeout
- use Task.Run instead Task.Factory.StartNew
- don't need to cancel the task, the cts will do the work

Now my code is simpler and it works:

```
private void Read_All_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Start timedout task that will send all necessary commands
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        oCommandSets.ReadAll(cts);
    }, cts.Token);
}
```

and

```
internal void ReadAll(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
     // [communication]

     if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(false);
     }
     else
     {
         ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(true);
     }
}
```

In any case I need to learn more about multithreading.

Comment: You can simplify: `ReadAllComplete?.Invoke(    !cts.IsCancellationRequested);`